# WPF ItemsControl with subpoints based on date

Tags: c#, wpf

Currently I have a `ObservableCollection<Foo> Bar = new ObservableCollection<Foo>();`.

`Foo` is build up like this

```
public class Foo(){
    private DateTime _scanStartTime;
    public DateTime ScanStartTime{
        get { return this._scanStartTime; }        
        set { this._scanStartTime = value; this.OnPropertyChanged("ScanStartTime");
    }
}
```

`Bar` contains **3 elements**.

```
Bar.Add(new Foo(new DateTime(Yesterday)));
Bar.Add(new Foo(new DateTime(Today)));
Bar.Add(new Foo(new DateTime(Today)));
```

*The code above is just for demonstration purpose.*

Now I want to display this 3 elements on my gui. I want to create something like this:

[image]

I'm struggeling with the subpoints. How can I add these? **Is it possible with WPF?** Should I split my `ObservableCollection Bar` into 2 and add them programmatically (C#) to the gui?

Comment: It seems to me that there are any number of ways to do this.  One you could have a ListView with an item template that had a label and a button both of which bound to StartScanTime.  What am I missing here.

Comment: @AQuirky thanks for the comment. I think I forgot something. There can be multiple `Foo's` created today. So it's not defined how many `Foo's` will be under one label.

Comment: There are still many possibilities.  You could do a DataGrid and have a grouping for all dates that are the same.  You could also do a tree.  With the data grid approach you can stick with a single flat collection.  The tree will require a nested list.  So a lot depends on how you want to organize the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF provides you with `TreeView` control. It allows you to define `HierarchicalDataTemplate` which is used to express object hierarchy (tree in your case) via view.

Here is a small sample:

```
<Grid>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Work}" ItemsSource="{Binding WorkItems}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Button Content="+" >
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,2,5,2"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFinalItem}" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Collection.Add(new Work
        {
            Name = "Clean my place",
            WorkItems = new ObservableCollection<Work>()
            {
                new Work { Name = "Today", IsFinalItem =true  },
                new Work { Name = "Tomorrow", IsFinalItem =true  },
                new Work { Name = "Monday", IsFinalItem =true  },
            }
        });
        Collection.Add(new Work { Name = "Clean Jim's place" });
        Collection.Add(new Work { Name = "Fix pc" });
        Collection.Add(new Work
        {
            Name = "Free",
            WorkItems = new ObservableCollection<Work>()
            {
                new Work { Name = "Today", IsFinalItem =true  },
                new Work { Name = "Tomorrow", IsFinalItem =true  },
                new Work { Name = "Monday", IsFinalItem =true  },
            }
        });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Work> Collection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Work>();
}
```

Work class:

```
public class Work
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Work> WorkItems { get; set; }
    public bool IsFinalItem { get; set; }
}
```

And the outcome:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this example! I will change the datastructure and will realize it with a treeview. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a `TreeView` and a better data structure. Build a data structure that represent the items in the order you want them to display.

I recommend using something like this (not fully implemented; just to give you an idea what I mean).

```
ObservableCollection<Bar> FooList;

public class Bar
{
    public ObservableCollection<Foo> Foos; 
    public DateTime Date;
}
```

Then you have a structured collection you can bind to a `TreeView`.